# js media queries when data is more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

- I have a css issue.
- when searchDateArea.length > 15 its working fine
- but when searchDateArea.length < 8 its failing.
- when its less than 8...I am seeing extra white block.
- is there any way to fix for all screen.
- providing whole code below

```

```
if ( $(window).width() > 739) { 
                //alert("I am here");
                $('.k-PLAYr-content').css({"height": "auto"});
                $('.k-PLAYr-content').css({"max-height": searchDateArea.length*70+"px"});
                $('.k-PLAYr-layout .k-PLAYr-times').eq(1).css({"height": "auto"});
                $('.k-PLAYr-layout .k-PLAYr-times').eq(1).css({"max-height": (searchDateArea.length*70)+"px"});
            }
            else {
                $('.k-PLAYr-content').css({"height": "auto"});
                $('.k-PLAYr-content').css({"max-height": searchDateArea.length*45+"px"});
```

```

Comment: That obviously not the "whole code". [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `$(window).width()` is not the way to check for window width regarding media queries. Use instead [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: @aaron thanks for your reply... but can you tell me the approach how to solve it

Comment: @A.Wolff hey then also we will have the length problem right??

Comment: Start by reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/18139767#47620138)